# Unnecessary parameters in query string in /me/questions when only "total" is requested

Tags: support

To get all the questions that I have asked, I am using Stack Exchange API, I am using [/me/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-questions). When only `total` is requested, `order` and `sort` are also given as parameters in the query string. It is unnecessary. Should there be some modifications in the API, to not have these unnecessary parameters when `total` is requested? Also, in the doc page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No unnecessary parameters are required. `order` and `sort` are always optional.

You can see this with these direct API calls:

- [/2.2/users/5035500/questions?site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/5035500/questions?site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE8F0_EMkjmC9zG)
- [/2.2/users/331508/questions?site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/331508/questions?site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE8F0_EMkjmC9zG)

It's hard to demonstrate a live link for [/me/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-questions#filter=!.UE8F0_EMkjmC9zG&site=stackoverflow), since it requires an access token, but if you call that route from an app or script, you'll see that `order` and `sort` are not required.

As for [the *doc pages*](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-questions#filter=!.UE8F0_EMkjmC9zG&site=stackoverflow), they automatically add those parameters as a *convenience*, not because they are required by the actual API.

Comment: When requesting only `total`, the unnecessary parameters don't come under 'convenience' category. Also, the doc page should be modified appropriately, i.e, the two parameters should be disabled.

Comment: Was the previous comment acceptance of the poor documentation? Also, correct documentation would help future programmers. Is incomplete, erroneous documentation of any use? I am from India, where we are expected to be flexible in every position.

Comment: The documentation is fine. The convenient demo tool is not the documentation; nor is it erroneous in any way (in this instance).  In fact, by providing those optional values explicitly: (1) it illustrates the default behavior/sort and (2) it encourages the developer to consider and specify the sort.  This is always a best practice and can help prevent "time bomb code".